# Is the coefficient of Uyx always the same as the coefficient of Uxy?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, determinant

Let's say i have the following partial differential equation and i want to find out the class of the PDE (hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptic):
$$
-2U_{xx} + U_{xy} + U_{yy} = 0
$$

Now, first i can extract visually the coefficients from the terms:
$$
coeff(U_{xx}) = -2 \\
coeff(U_{xy}) = 1 \\
coeff(U_{yy}) = 1
$$
I could calculate the determinant of the coefficient matrix to be able to classify the PDE but i need to know the coefficient of $U_{yx}$.

Since the term is not presented in the equation, i would assume that the coefficient of $coeff(U_{yx}) = 0$ but since $U_{xy} = U_{yx}, coeff(U_{xy}) = coeff(U_{yx})$.

So either we have this matrix, where $coeff(U_{yx}) = 0$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or this matrix, where $coeff(U_{xy}) = coeff(U_{yx})$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: If $U$ is a $C^2-$ function, then by Schwarz: $U_{xy}=U_{yx}.$

Comment: @Fred Ok but that does not clarify if i should use the same coefficient from $U_{xy}$ for $U_{yx}$